# sql query to delete only one duplicate row

Tags: sql-server

I've a table with some duplicate rows in it. I want to delete only one duplicate row.

For example I'v 9 duplicate rows so should delete only one row and should show 8 remaining rows.

example

date calling called duration timestampp

```
2012-06-19 10:22:45.000 165 218 155 1.9 121
2012-06-19 10:22:45.000 165 218 155 1.9 121
2012-06-19 10:22:45.000 165 218 155 1.9 121
2012-06-19 10:22:45.000 165 218 155 1.9 121
```

from above date should delete only one row and should show 3 rows

```
2012-06-19 10:22:45.000 165 218 155 1.9 100
2012-06-19 10:22:45.000 165 218 155 1.9 100
2012-06-19 10:22:45.000 165 218 155 1.9 100
```

from above date should delete only one row and should show 2 rows

How can I do this?

Comment: can you please format the data so it's more readble?

Comment: There are five column names listed but six columns in output. And how does the last column change from 121 to 100? If the source had two rows with 121 and two rows with 100, would you delete two rows or one? (In other words, is duplicate based on date alone?)

Answer (score 11):

This solution allows you to delete one row from each set of duplicates (rather than just handling a single block of duplicates at a time):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT [date], rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
    [date], calling, called, duration, [timestamp]
    ORDER BY [date])
  FROM dbo.UnspecifiedTableName
)
DELETE x WHERE rn = 2;
```

As an aside, both `[date]` and `[timestamp]` are terrible choices for column names...

Comment: whats the meaning of ;WITH x AS??

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521 It's called a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2005+ you can do the following:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [date], calling, called, duration, [timestamp] ORDER BY 1) RN
    FROM YourTable
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a primary key on the table?

What makes a row a duplicate? Same time? same date? all columns being the same?

If you have a primary key you can use the TOP function to select only one record and delete that one row:

```
Delete from [tablename] where id in (select top 1 id from [tablename] where [clause])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't  mind the order of these rows there is a command in MySQL:

```
DELETE TOP (numberOfRowsToDelete) FROM db.tablename WHERE {condition for ex id = 5};
```

Comment: and of course you can use thene WHERE statement to specify which date to delete.

Comment: The OP asked for a SQL Server solution.

Answer (score -1):

Since I don't have the schema, I'd a possible solution in steps:

1. Apply a row number to the select of all columns
2. Make a group by with those columns and delete the min(rownumber) in each group

   ---

Edit:

The rownumber is in a inner query and will have the rownumber incrementing in all rows. In the outer query I make the group by of the inner query and select the min(rownumber) for each group. Since each group is composed by duplicated rows, I then remove the min(rownumber) for each group.

Comment: MIN will always be 1 for each group, if partitioned by the same columns. This means you'll also delete rows that *don't* have duplicates, unless you also add HAVING. Which makes it even more complex than solutions already posted, IMHO.

Comment: @AaronBertrand nop, the rownumber is in a inner query and will have the rownumber incrementing in all rows. In the outer query I make the group by of the inner query and select the min(rownumber) for each group. Since each group is composed by duplicated rows, I then remove the min(rownumber) for each group. Did you understand?

Comment: With a better description, sure, but it doesn't match your first description. Code would have been more useful and self-explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

using `LIMIT 1` will help you delete only `1 ROW` that matches your `DELETE` query:

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name`='value' LIMIT 1;
```

**BEFORE**:

```
+----------------------+
| id  |  column_name   |
+-----+----------------+
| 1   |  value         |
+-----+----------------+
| 2   |  value         |
+-----+----------------+
| 3   |  value         |
+-----+----------------+
| 4   |  value         |
+-----+----------------+
```

**AFTER**:

```
+----------------------+
| id  |  column_name   |
+-----+----------------+
| 1   |  value         |
+-----+----------------+
| 2   |  value         |
+-----+----------------+
| 3   |  value         |
+-----+----------------+
```