# Deleting only 1 row from duplication records in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
Select * From T_Trans_HHT Where transType='OUT' and docNum='15/01979' order by ItemCode
```

i am getting duplicate records like this: my each item code coming 2 times,so i want to remove one item code row from my table?
my out put like this:
[image]

In this i want to delete one row,how i can do this?

Comment: All columns duplicate? If so, use `select distinct`. I assume you want to **show** only unique records, not actually delete records

Comment: Try to use existing suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122749/sql-query-to-delete-only-one-duplicate-row

Answer (score 2):

using CTE and Row_number

```
 ;with CTE AS 
    (Select *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Docnum,location
     ORDER BY transDATEtime desc)RN 
    From T_Trans_HHT 
    Where transType='OUT' and 
    docNum='15/01979' )

    delete from CTE where RN = 1
```

OR use

```
DISTINCT and Group BY all columns 
select distinct col1,col2 ... from table
Group by all columns
```

Comment: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: while i use your first query

Comment: @Jonathan : Don't need of `ORDER BY` after the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: yeah i agree with you

Comment: after deleting order by also am not getting proper result, 
while i executing my query i am getting 20 records,each item code duplicating 1 time,i need to get only 10 rows? how i can get that?

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE TOP(1) From T_Trans_HHT 
Where transType='OUT' 
and docNum='15/01979' 
order by ItemCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `CTE`.

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (
        PARTITION BY ItemCode
        ORDER BY ItemCode
    ), * FROM T_Trans_HHT 
    WHERE transType='OUT' 
    AND docNum='15/01979'
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1;
```

Comment: ullas,,i tryed this query,but not getting proper result

Comment: while i executing my query i am getting 20 records,each item code duplicating 1 time,i need to get only 10 rows? how i can get that?

Comment: @jasbacker : You need to delete the duplicate from the table right?

Comment: With my query, it will delete one row having `transType='OUT' AND docNum='15/01979'`. And if you want to delete each duplicate row without any condition, then remove the `WHERE` clause from the query and execute. And remember, always keep a backup before `DELETE`, `UPDATE` and all.

Comment: sir,in transType='OUT' AND docNum='15/01979' this condition i have 20 records with different item code,i need only 10 records,becouse another 10 records is exact duplicate,i already give example of 1 item code

Comment: @jasbacker : only `ItemCode` is different right? Then in query, change `PARTITION BY ItemCode`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE ....
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```